# Identify classic City sets from box of assembled parts

Tags: set-identification, city

I have quite a few models: a gas station, airports, police station, and a lot more including a battery powered cart. They are all built on gray road baseplates. I also have trees, benches, people, police cars, others cars, and a service station or fire department

[image: helicopter]

[image: cargo plane]

Answer (score 2):

From left to right in your first photo:

Police Station (6384):

[image: 6384]

Fire Copter 1:

[image: 6685]

Motorcycle Shop (6373):

[image: 6373]

Fire Patrol Copter (6657):

[image: 6657]

Fire Station (6382):

[image: 6382]

Your second photo includes:

Gas Station (6375):

[image: 6375]

Delivery Center (6377):

[image: 6377]

Paramedic Unit (6364):

[image: 6364]

I may have missed some smaller sets, but based on your two pictures, that's what stuck out at me.

Comment: Oh my childhood ... endless hours with that Fire Station :)

Comment: There might be a https://brickset.com/sets/6634-1/Stock-Car in front of that police station (first photo), albeit with different (red) wheels.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper That's certainly possible.